# Using full screen Activity

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I am making a simple game and so far I've been using the Blank Activity. Now I want it to cover the entire screen, Will I need to Recode the entire thing using a FullScreen Activity? I've tried looking for something online but every thing i came across had adding this bit:​

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Which causes the app to crash as soon as it is launched on a device. SO please if anyone can show me my error.

Here is a link to the logcat output as well as the game code

[Logcat and game code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_l90NU0fx6Um5MOVBSNUlDYlU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Show us your Logcat, and we'll show you the error.

Comment: Add it to your question.

Comment: Already did, But since the Logcat was too long I uploaded a link to the file  using google docs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this to set activity to fullscreen:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

You can put this code in `onCreate()` method

Comment: Essentially This wasn't first working as I had the target SDK set all the way back to Froyo. Once I changed that to KitKat, This worked like a charm

Comment: @Michele Lacorte I am experiencing a white coloured bar when my navigation drawer goes off in android L?

Comment: I think @t-kashima xml solution below in the answers is quite nice. Check it out. No need to duplicate this accepted answers' code everywhere if you have a style that defines fullscreen.

Comment: Tried this. The activity only looks fullscreen after `onCreate`, but the status bar appears when the activity is resumed. XML solution works better.

Answer (score 26):

You can try following code.

style.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoTitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FullScreenActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
```

Comment: best solution is here i think.Should have more upvotes.

Comment: Upvoted, but it doesn't work well. Tested it and it shows the soft buttons when resuming the activity.

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers above works correctly; they have problems with the `onResume()` method, and end up showing the soft keys.

The correct way to do it is pretty straightforward. Override this method in the `Activity` that should be fullscreen:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

That's if you want "Sticky Immersion". Check out the full doc [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html), and decide what is better for your use case.

Comment: Thank you! This should be the accepted answer. I had this in `onResume()` as so many stack overflow answers suggest, and it worked 99% of the time, making it hard to debug. You saved me having to run this code every few seconds as a workaround.

Comment: @user1516661 I was confused at first with everyone saying to put it on the `onResume()` method too :)

Answer (score 2):

What you wanted is called Imersive mode, which works on Android 4.4 and Above

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Official Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Answer (score 2):

In **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<activity
       android:name=".Launch"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" > <!-- This line is important -->

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

and your class should extends Activity not AppCompatActivity...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to your manifest file and add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to your 
`<activity />` or `<application />` tag in your Manifest file depending upon your requirement.