# Hidding home button and back button on Android

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

In styles I've

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

and in the manifest file, in application I've specified my theme, but home button and back button are still visible, what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using full screen Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069461/using-full-screen-activity)

Answer (score 1):

You must use `Immersive` feature of android. Immersive mode will be only working on devices with KitKat and higher. This, what is weird on your side, is fact, that basing on your words, you cannot even get these flags like this:

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
```

(or part of them). If it is this way, then it is looking, that your compileSdkVersion is lower, than it should be. On start I would advise you to update compileSdkVersion.

When you will do this, and you would like to use these flags please in places, where you want to use immersive mode add conditions, that will be looking like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    int UI_OPTIONS = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(UI_OPTIONS);
}
```

Then it should not mess on older OS.

Comment: okay, I've done it but it's blue and white and I want to make it black and I didn't get how can I change

Comment: Change the default theme settings.

Comment: can you tell me where it's getting color for home button bar?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following two way to achieve what you need

- getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) to remove the home
  button from the action bar.
- ActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
  i prefer you use the first 1

Comment: make sure your activity is declaired as                                                    
<activity
            android:name="your name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">       </activity>           



  and in style  you specify the style as     ~~
                                                                   
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar"><item name="windowActionBar">false</item><item name="windowNoTitle">true</item></style>