# How to create a fully unclosable ProgressDialog?

Tags: java, android, dialog, progressdialog

How to show a `ProgressDialog` from a background service that is unclosable in any way, displayed above whole screen, above any app, including keys? I mean a dialog exactly like the "Power off.. shutting down" one that is displayed when phone is shutting down, when you can neither do anything to make it disappear nor click anything below it.

PS. If the app needs to be a system app to create such dialog, that's not a problem for me.

Comment: I've just found this, I'm trying to use it somehow https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a full screen activity [Using full screen Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069461/using-full-screen-activity) prevent back navigation by overriding onBackPressed()
[Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Comment: what about home key?

Comment: yeah, home and app list buttons would still be clickable

Comment: so according to the question your answer is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
ProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: progressdialog from a service?

Comment: I'd be able to close this by using the back, home or app list button